# Want to add subsection numbering to custom .cls file

Tags: numbering

I got this style file from a journal and I modded it.  Currently, the theorem numbering scheme uses only two digits: one for the section and one for the item.  I don't like it that the item number doesn't reset to one in each new subsection.  I want to add a third number to the numbering scheme so that it uses (Section.Subsection.Item).  The first theorem in the third subsection of the second section should be Theorem 2.3.1.  How can I can change this?  Below, I include a sample tex file and I will put the CLS file in a comment.  THANKS!!!

### TEX FILE:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{physics_custom}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{mainthm}[thm]{Main Theorem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem*{xrem}{Remark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{document}

%% Note that the first letters in the title are capitalized

%% Provide an abbreviation of the title, to be used in running heads.

\TitleHead{Paper about Hodor }
\title{Paper about Hodor}


\AuthorHead{Jim Bob}
\author{Jim \textsc{Bob}\footnote{Tooker: jim.bob@gmail.com;}}



\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here
\end{abstract}

\section{first section}

\begin{rem}
    I want to change it to make this Remark 1.0.1
\end{rem}

\subsection{first section, first subsection}

\begin{thm}
    Currently, this shows up as Theorem 1.2 but I want to change it to be Theorem 1.1.1 because it is the first theorem of the first subsection of the first subsection.
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
    Should be Lemma 1.1.2
\end{lem}


\subsection{first section, second subsection}

\begin{exa}
    This example really shows what I don't like.  Currently it is Example 1.4 but I'd like it to be Example 1.2.1
\end{exa}


\section{second section}

\begin{cor}
    You probably get it by now, but this should be Corollary 2.0.1
\end{cor}


\begin{cor}
    Should be Corollary 2.0.2
\end{cor}


\begin{cor}
    Should be Corollary 2.0.3
\end{cor}



\subsection{second section, first subsection}

\begin{thm}
    Should be Theorem 2.1.1
\end{thm}



\subsection{second section, second subsection}


\begin{thm}
    Should be Theorem 2.2.1
\end{thm}


\subsection{second section, third subsection}


\begin{thm}
    Should be Theorem 2.3.1
\end{thm}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the way the number is displayed for the theorems, you will have to do:

```
\renewcommand*{\thethm}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{thm}}
```

This will redefine the way the thm counter is displayed. Since all your theorems share the thm counter, they will all be displayed the way you want.

Then, when you write `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` it means that each time you will use the environment `thm`, the thm counter will increase by one and will be reset to 0 each time you use `\section`.
Given the behavior you want, you should use `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]` so that the counter is reset each time you use `\subsection`.